# Credit Card Scanner - flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, credit-card, card.io

Is there a credit card scanner API for flutter? CardIO Plugin for flutter is not working at all. It is not recognizing the package **package:flutter_card_io/flutter_card_io.dart** which I am trying to import.

Details are present in
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_card_io

I get the error message. Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_card_io/flutter_card_io.dart

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get the error message. Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_card_io/flutter_card_io.dart'

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted. Did I ask anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

flutter_card_io >=0.0.2 which requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0

They have fixed, but still not published to package site.
https://github.com/procedurallygenerated/flutter_card_io/issues/1

Edit:
you can get it from git directly like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_card_io:
    git:
      https://github.com/procedurallygenerated/flutter_card_io.git
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this package to the pubspec.yaml file, and then run 'packages get' to update the dependencies. See:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_card_io#-installing-tab-